# SQLite DB Deleted After Restarting App

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

For some reason when I restart my Android app, the database I created previously is gone. My helper class is shown below. I create an instance of the helper class in a separate fragment and only call the following functions from the fragment:

```
helper = new LocationBaseHelper(getActivity());
helper.insertEntry(blah blah);
```

If it matters, I create the database in the "onCreateView( )" fragment class. I test the size of the database each time I add, so I know that it is indeed adding to the database. When I restart and check the size, it is 0 again. Here is my helper class.

// Edit

If someone could explain how SQLite DBs behave on Android, that would also help. If I call the helper constructor multiple times, do multiple DBs get created? Do they overwrite previous ones? What if I call it from different fragments/activities/services? Thank you.

```
public class LocationBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int VERSION = 1;
private static final String D​A​T​A​B​A​S​E​_​N​A​M​E​ = "locationBase.db";
private int mNumberOfElements = 0;

public LocationBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, D​A​T​A​B​A​S​E​_​N​A​M​E​, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + LocationTable.NAME + " (" +
            LocationTable.Cols.DATE_TIME + " text, " +
            LocationTable.Cols.LATITUDE + " text, " +
            LocationTable.Cols.LONGITUDE + " text )"
    );
}

// do nothing
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}

public void insertEntry(String date_time, String latitude, String longitude){
    mNumberOfElements++;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(LocationTable.Cols.DATE_TIME,date_time);
    content.put(LocationTable.Cols.LATITUDE,latitude);
    content.put(LocationTable.Cols.LONGITUDE,longitude);
    db.insert(LocationTable.NAME,null,content);
}

public ArrayList<String> getEntireDatabase(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + LocationTable.NAME,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    do{
        String value = (String) cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocationTable.Cols.DATE_TIME)) + " " +
                (String) cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocationTable.Cols.LATITUDE)) + " " +
                (String) cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocationTable.Cols.LONGITUDE));
        values.add(0,value);

    }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    return values;
}

public int size(){return mNumberOfElements;}
}
```

Comment: If by checking the size you mean `mNumberOfElements` - of course your field values start at their default values. To count the number of rows in a database table, use a `COUNT(*)` query.

Comment: You're right, I think it's not getting deleted then. I would do something like `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + LocationTable.NAME,null);`    right? @laalto

Comment: Yes that would be one way to efficiently count the number of rows in a table.

Comment: Thanks it helped me solve a part of my problem, is there a way I can give you something for your help?

Comment: I expanded my comments to an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I test the size of the database each time I add, so I know that it is indeed adding to the database. When I restart and check the size, it is 0 again

If by "check the size" you mean this stuff:

> ```
> private int mNumberOfElements = 0;
>
> public void insertEntry(String date_time, String latitude, String longitude){
>     mNumberOfElements++;
>
> ...
>
> public int size(){return mNumberOfElements;}
> }
> ```

then of course an another instance of your helper starts counting inserts from 0 again as fields are initialized to their default values.

To count the number of elements in a database table, do a `COUNT(*)` query. For example:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
long numberOfRows = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + LocationTable.NAME, null);
```